# Types for parser combinators

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

If I have a parser `a : Parser A` and a parser `b : Parser B` then I can combine it into a parser `a | b : Parser (Either A B)`. This works but gets a little tricky when you start adding more alternatives and getting types like `Either A (Either B C)`. I can imagine flattening the previous type into something like `Alternative A B C`. Is there a standard transformation I can perform or am I stuck with generating a whole bunch of boilerplate for types like `Alternative A B C ...`.

Comment: You could use the [Data Types a la carte](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.101.4131) method here, but I find that it's a lot easier and uses a lot less boilerplate to just write an ADT to handle it.

Comment: If you chose to try out the Datatype a la carte method, there is a [package which implements it.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.8.1.3/docs/Data-Comp-Sum.html)

Comment: Depending upon the circumstances, you can combine the type `A` and `B` into sum data type to provide a single parser type. I can give you an example if you are interested.

Comment: @bheklilr Would love to see an example of that method mentioned in the paper.

Comment: @Sibi It might take longer than this question gets answered, but I'll see if I can throw something together along those lines.  If it works for combining functors, then I imagine you could simply use the `(Const A :+: Const B :+: Const C)` functor to store the values (we aren't actually interested in the functor instance itself, just being able to combine them easily)

Comment: I suddenly wonder if one could in the future extend GHC to make a `[]` poly-kinded enough that you could write the type as `Alternative [A,B,C]`.

Comment: A custom datatype directly representing the actual sum type you want is exactly the way to go here.

Comment: Ørjan Johansen: the future is now

Comment: @rampion Oh you are right! I first only tested `:k []` and it seemed to only allow `*` contents, but after further testing `:k [Either Int, Maybe]` and such things already work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the interesting thing about `Either` is that you can use it as a type-level `cons` operator.

```
A `Either` (B `Either` (C `Either` (D `Either` Void))) --> [A,B,C,D]
```

So all we need do is make that explicit. You'll need ghc-7.8 to support closed data families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
-- ...

type family OneOf (as :: [*]) :: * where
  OneOf '[a] = a
  OneOf (a ': as) = Either a (OneOf as)
```

Now you can write your types much more succinctly:

```
aorborc :: Parser (OneOf '[A, B, C])
aorborc = a | (b | c)
```

It's still `Either` under the hood, so you can still easily interoperate with all existing code that uses `Either`, which is nice.

Comment: `OneOf '[] = Void` was left out to avoid a (possibly unnecessary) import.

Comment: You don't need `Void` if you define `OneOf` the way I defined `U` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205585/is-there-a-compiler-extension-for-untagged-union-types-in-haskell/26228038#26228038). Just avoid writing the `'[a]` case, and start with `'[a, b]`.

Comment: Christian Conkle: I was saying we would need something like `Data.Void` to define `OneOf '[]` and make `OneOf` total. Following `U`'s example would only make it **less** total, as `OneOf '[a]` would no longer be defined.

Answer (score 3):

Either is just one possible sum type in Haskell, and because of the ready made class instances and helper functions is useful for many cases, but becomes considerably clunkier when you nest it.

The best approach for a parser is to create your own data type that mirrors the structure you're parsing and parse directly into that. Let's make a partial toy example about a toy language.

```
data Statement = TypeDec String Type
                 DataDec String [Constructor]
                 FunctionDec String LambdaExpression

statement :: Parser Statement
statement = TypeDec <$> string "type " *> identifier <*> string " = " *> type
            <|> DataDec <$> string "data " *> identifier <*> string " = " *> many constructor
            <|> FunctionDec <$> identifier <*> string " = " *> lambdaExpression
```

In this way, both your data structure and your code mirror the productions in the grammar you're parsing. The great benefit to that is that your data is type safe, clear and ready to use as soon as it's parsed.

<sub>(I can never remember the fixities of `*>` and `<*`, so I've probably done it the way you need brackets or something, but hopefully you get the idea.)</sub>