# Is there a compiler-extension for untagged union types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

In some languages (#racket/typed, for example), the programmer can specify a union type without discriminating against it, for instance, the type `(U Integer String)` captures integers and strings, without tagging them `(I Integer) (S String)` in a `data IntOrStringUnion = ...` form or anything like that. 
Is there a way to do the same in Haskell?

Comment: You can create a type class and only make `Integer` and `String` instances of it.

Comment: I don't know if I undertand the question correctly - can you explain a bit what you want to do with this? (Some kind of annonymous types?)

Comment: What would taglessness gain you? How would you distinguish between them? What possible operation can you do on something if you don't know which it is?

Comment: You're aware Haskell has full polymorphism? You can make `data Tree a = ...` and store `Int`s in it or `String`s in it. It's considered good practice to allow _any_ type in your data structure even if you plan on only using it for a few, since you may be able to use handy general constructor classes like Functor, Applicative, Monad etc.

Comment: In Scheme, _every_ value is tagged with its type, which is why you have `string?`, `number?`, etc. Haskell doesn't do this, so when you do need tagging you have to do it yourself.

Comment: No, Haskell doesn't have untagged unions.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  The only reason you can do this kind of thing in Scheme is that all values are tagged at runtime, so there are actually interesting things you can do with a type that is `IntOrStringUnion`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `Either` is what you're looking for... ish.

In Haskell terms, I'd describe what you're looking for as an *anonymous sum type*. By anonymous, I mean that it doesn't have a defined name (like something with a `data` declaration). By sum type, I mean a data type that can have one of several (distinguishable) types; a tagged union or such. (If you're not familiar with this terminology, try [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) for starters.)

We have a well-known idiomatic anonymous *product* type, which is just a tuple. If you want to have *both* an `Int` and a `String`, you just smush them together with a comma: `(Int, String)`. And tuples (seemingly) can go on forever--`(Int, String, Double, Word)`, and you can pattern-match the same way. (There's a limit, but never mind.)

The well-known idiomatic anonymous *sum* type is `Either`, from `Data.Either` (and the `Prelude`):

```
data  Either a b  =  Left a | Right b
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Typeable)
```

It has some shortcomings, most prominently a `Functor` instance that favors `Right` in a way that's odd in this context. The problem is that chaining it introduces a lot of awkwardness: the type ends up like `Either (Int (Either String (Either Double Word)))`. Pattern matching is even more awkward, as others have noted.

I just want to note that we can get closer to (what I understand to be) the Racket use case. From my extremely brief Googling, it looks like in Racket you can use functions like `isNumber?` to determine what type is actually in a given value of a union type. In Haskell, we usually do that with case analysis (pattern matching), but that's awkward with `Either`, and function using simple pattern-matching will likely end up hard-wired to a particular union type. We can do better.

### `IsNumber?`

I'm going to write a function I think is an idiomatic Haskell stand-in for `isNumber?`. First, we don't like doing Boolean tests and then running functions that assume their result; instead, we tend to just convert to `Maybe` and go from there. So the function's type will end with `-> Maybe Int`. (Using `Int` as a stand-in for now.)

But what's on the left hand of the arrow? "Something that might be an Int -- or a String, or whatever other types we put in the union." Uh, okay. So it's going to be one of a number of types. That sounds like typeclass, so we'll put a constraint and a type variable on the left hand of the arrow: `MightBeInt a => a -> Maybe Int`. Okay, let's write out the class:

```
class MightBeInt a where
  isInt   :: a -> Maybe Int
  fromInt :: Int -> a
```

Okay, now how do we write the instances? Well, we know if the first parameter to `Either` is `Int`, we're golden, so let's write that out. (Incidentally, if you want a nice exercise, only look at the `instance ... where` parts of these next three code blocks, and try to implement that class members yourself.)

```
instance MightBeInt (Either Int b) where
  isInt (Left i) = Just i
  isInt _ = Nothing
  fromInt = Left
```

Fine. And ditto if `Int` is the second parameter:

```
instance MightBeInt (Either a Int) where
  isInt (Right i) = Just i
  isInt _ = Nothing
  fromInt = Right
```

But what about `Either String (Either Bool Int)`? The trick is to recurse on the right hand type: if it's not `Int`, is it an instance of `MightBeInt` itself?

```
instance MightBeInt b => MightBeInt (Either a b) where
  isInt (Right xs) = isInt xs
  isInt _ = Nothing
  fromInt = Right . fromInt
```

(Note that these all require `FlexibleInstances` and `OverlappingInstances`.) It took me a long time to get a feel for writing and reading these class instances; don't worry if this instance is surprising. The punch line is that we can now do this:

```
anInt1 :: Either Int String
anInt1 = fromInt 1

anInt2 :: Either String (Either Int Double)
anInt2 = fromInt 2

anInt3 :: Either String Int
anInt3 = fromInt 3

notAnInt :: Either String Int
notAnInt = Left "notint"

ghci> isInt anInt3
Just 3
ghci> isInt notAnInt
Nothing
```

Great!

### Generalizing

Okay, but now do we need to write another type class for each type we want to look up? Nope! We can parameterize the class by the type we want to look up! It's a pretty mechanical translation; the only question is how to tell the compiler what type we're looking for, and that's where [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.2/docs/Data-Proxy.html) comes to the rescue. (If you don't want to install `tagged` or run `base` 4.7, just define `data Proxy a = Proxy`. It's nothing special, but you'll need `PolyKinds`.)

```
class MightBeA t a where
  isA   :: proxy t -> a -> Maybe t
  fromA :: t -> a

instance MightBeA t t where
  isA _ = Just
  fromA = id

instance MightBeA t (Either t b) where
  isA _ (Left i) = Just i
  isA _ _ = Nothing
  fromA = Left

instance MightBeA t b => MightBeA t (Either a b) where
  isA p (Right xs) = isA p xs
  isA _ _ = Nothing
  fromA = Right . fromA

ghci> isA (Proxy :: Proxy Int) anInt3
Just 3
ghci> isA (Proxy :: Proxy String) notAnInt
Just "notint"
```

Now the usability situation is... better. The main thing we've lost, by the way, is the exhaustiveness checker.

### Notational Parity With `(U String Int Double)`

For fun, in GHC 7.8 we can use `DataKinds` and `TypeFamilies` to eliminate the infix type constructors in favor of type-level lists. (In Haskell, you can't have one type constructor--like `IO` or `Either`--take a variable number of parameters, but a type-level list is just one parameter.) It's just a few lines, which I'm not really going to explain:

```
type family OneOf (as :: [*]) :: * where
  OneOf '[] = Void
  OneOf '[a] = a
  OneOf (a ': as) = Either a (OneOf as)
```

Note that you'll need to import [`Data.Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.6.1/docs/Data-Void.html). Now we can do this:

```
anInt4 :: OneOf '[Int, Double, Float, String]
anInt4 = fromInt 4

ghci> :kind! OneOf '[Int, Double, Float, String]
OneOf '[Int, Double, Float, String] :: *
= Either Int (Either Double (Either Float [Char]))
```

In other words, `OneOf '[Int, Double, Float, String]` is the same as `Either Int (Either Double (Either Float [Char]))`.

Comment: It's probably possible to use the [visible type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application) extension to eliminate the `Proxy`, but you'd have to work out how to get the type variables into the correct order. GHC seems to put `a` before `t` by default.

Comment: But you won’t get runtime poly using typeclass. Which might be needed in cases when the input type does not provide the result type information and only the input’s term does.

Answer (score 7):

You need some kind of tagging because you need to be able to check if a value is actually an `Integer` or a `String` to use it for anything. One way to alleviate having to create a custom ADT for every combination is to use a type such as

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data a :+: b = L a | R b

infixr 6 :+:

returnsIntOrString :: Integer -> Integer :+: String
returnsIntOrString i
    | i `rem` 2 == 0 = R "Even"
    | otherwise      = L (i * 2)

returnsOneOfThree :: Integer -> Integer :+: String :+: Bool
returnsOneOfThree i
    | i `rem` 2 == 0 = (R . L) "Even"
    | i `rem` 3 == 0 = (R . R) False
    | otherwise      = L (i * 2)
```

Comment: From the comments on the original question I think I'm just not writing idiomatic haskell yet, but this does what I'd like. I bet the typeclass with limited implementations is really what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot, all.