# Haskell: Why use Proxy?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, a [Proxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Proxy.html) is a *type witness* value that makes it easy to pass some types around

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

An example use is here in [json-schema](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-schema-0.7.3.0/docs/Data-JSON-Schema-Types.html):

```
class JSONSchema a where
  schema :: Proxy a -> Schema
```

so you could do `schema (Proxy :: Proxy (Int,Char))` to obtain what the JSON representation for an Int-Char-Tuple would be (probably an array).

---

**Why do people use proxies?** It seems to me that the same could be accomplished by

```
class JSONSchema a where
  schema :: Schema a
```

similar to how the `Bounded` typeclass works.
I first thought it might be easier to get the schema of some given value when using proxies, but that doesn't seem to be true:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

schemaOf :: JSONSchema a => a -> Schema a

schemaOf (v :: x) = schema (Proxy :: Proxy x)  -- With proxy

schemaOf (v :: x) = schema :: Schema x         -- With `:: a`
schemaOf _ = schema                            -- Even simpler with `:: a`
```

Also, one might worry about whether the `Proxy` values are actually eradicated at runtime, which is an optimisation problem that doesn't exists when using the `:: a` approach.

If the `:: a` approach as taken by `Bounded` achieves the same result with shorter code and less worries about optimisation, why do people use proxies? **What are the benefits of proxies?**

---

**EDIT:** Some answers and commenters rightfully pointed out that the `:: a` approach taints the `data Schema = ...` type with a "useless" type parameter - at least from the perspective of the plain data structure itself, which doesn't ever use the `a` ([see here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-schema-0.7.3.0/docs/Data-JSON-Schema-Types.html#t:Schema)).

The suggestion is to use the phantom type [`Tagged s b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html) instead, which allows to separate the two concerns (`Tagged a Schema` combines the non-parametric schema type with a type variable `a`), which is strictly better than the `:: a` approach.

So my the question should better be **What are the benefits of proxies vs. the tagged approach?**

Comment: In this case there is a choice, but an example where you want a proxy is `typeRep :: Proxy a -> TypeRep`.  The alternative would be to use the old way of doing it, `typfeOf :: a -> Typeable`.  But that latter is unpleasant because you often have to use it with `typeOf (undefined :: T)`, and IMHO it's better to use `typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy T)`.

Comment: I fail to see the analogy with `Bounded`. Using a type-tag as provided for example by https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html is a valid alternative to using Proxies. It somewhat depends on whether you want the extra type argument on the result type or not.

Comment: @kosmikus You are right, using `Tagged` would be the cleaner way to not pollute my `Schema` with a useless `a` (since for `Schema` the `a` would actually never be used on the left hand side of the data declaration). I will add a bit to the end of the question to say that a better question would be about the difference between `Proxy` and `Tagged`.

Comment: @augustss I do not understand yet why for `typeRep` you need the proxy. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Regarding `typeRep`: Parameterizing `TypeRep` by the type represented would destroy its usefulness. Without a proxy, the type of `typeRep` would be `Typeable a => TypeRep`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Two examples, one where `Proxy` is necessary, and one where `Proxy` doesn't fundamentally change the types, but I tend to use it anyway.

### `Proxy` necessary

`Proxy` or some equivalent trick is necessary when there's some intermediate type, not exposed in the normal type signature, that you want the consumer to be able to specify. Perhaps the intermediate type changes the semantics, such as `read . show :: String -> String`. With `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled, I'd write

```
f :: forall proxy a. (Read a, Show a) => proxy a -> String -> String
f _ = (show :: a -> String) . read
```

```
> f (Proxy :: Proxy Int) "3"
"3"
> f (Proxy :: Proxy Bool) "3"
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The proxy parameter allows me to expose `a` as a type parameter. `show . read` is kind of a stupid example. A better situation may be where some algorithm uses a generic collection internally, where the collection type selected has some performance characteristics that you want to the consumer to be able to control without requiring (or permitting) them to provide or receive the intermediate value.

Something like this, using [`fgl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) types, where we *don't* want to expose the internal `Data` type. (Perhaps someone can suggest an appropriate algorithm for this example?)

```
f :: Input -> Output
f = g . h
  where
    h :: Gr graph Data => Input -> graph Data
    g :: Gr graph Data => graph Data -> Output
```

Exposing a proxy argument would allow the user to select between a Patricia tree or a normal tree graph implementation.

### `Proxy` as API or implementation convenience

I sometimes use `Proxy` as a tool to choose a typeclass instance, especially in recursive or inductive class instances. Consider the `MightBeA` class I wrote in [this answer about using nested `Either`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205585/is-there-a-compiler-extension-for-untagged-union-types-in-haskell/26228038#26228038):

```
class MightBeA t a where
  isA   :: proxy t -> a -> Maybe t
  fromA :: t -> a

instance MightBeA t t where
  isA _ = Just
  fromA = id

instance MightBeA t (Either t b) where
  isA _ (Left i) = Just i
  isA _ _ = Nothing
  fromA = Left

instance MightBeA t b => MightBeA t (Either a b) where
  isA p (Right xs) = isA p xs
  isA _ _ = Nothing
  fromA = Right . fromA
```

The idea is to extract a `Maybe Int` from, say, `Either String (Either Bool Int)`. The type of `isA` is basically `a -> Maybe t`. There are two reasons to use a proxy here:

First, it eliminates type signatures for the consumer. You can call `isA` as `isA (Proxy :: Proxy Int)` rather than `isA :: MightBeA Int a => a -> Maybe Int`.

Second, it's easier for me to think through the inductive case by just passing the proxy through. With `ScopedTypeVariables`, the class can be rewritten without a proxy argument; the inductive case would be implemented as

```
instance MightBeA' t b => MightBeA' t (Either a b) where
  -- no proxy argument
  isA' (Right xs) = (isA' :: b -> Maybe t) xs
  isA' _ = Nothing
  fromA' = Right . fromA'
```

This isn't really a big change in this case; if the type signature of `isA` was considerably more complex, using the proxy would be a big improvement.

When the use is exclusively for implementation convenience, I'd typically export a wrapper function so the user needn't provide the proxy.

### `Proxy` vs. `Tagged`

In all of my examples, the type parameter `a` doesn't add anything useful to the output type itself. (In the first two examples, it's unrelated to the output type; in the last example, it's *redundant* of the output type.) If I returned a `Tagged a x`, the consumer would invariably untag it immediately. Furthermore, the user will have to write out the type of `x` in full, which is sometimes very inconvenient because it's some complicated intermediate type. (Maybe [someday we'll be able to use `_` in type signatures...](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PartialTypeSignatures))

(I'm interested to hear other answers on this sub-question; I've literally never written anything using `Tagged` (without rewriting it in short order using `Proxy`) and wonder whether I'm missing something.)

Comment: Two great examples, I hadn't thought about these use cases.

Comment: `PartialTypeSignatures` is here now! `Tagged` is, indeed, much less painful than it used to be.

Answer (score 10):

Ultimately they will perform the same functionality and you see them in either style. Sometimes it's appropriate to phantom tag your values, sometimes you'd like to think of them as untyped.

The other alternative is to use `Data.Tagged`.

```
class JSONSchema a where
  schema :: Tagged a Schema
```

Here we have something of the best of both worlds since a `Tagged` `Schema` has phantom type information necessary to resolve the instance but we can trivially disregard that information using `unTagged :: Tagged s b -> b`.

I would say the driving question, couched in terms of this example, should be "Do I want to consider typed operations on `Schema`s?". If the answer is "no", then you will be biased toward the `Proxy` or `Tagged` approaches. If the answer is "yes", then `Schema a` is a great solution.

As a final note, you can use the `Proxy` approach (somewhat hackily) without any imports. You see this sometimes in the style

```
class JSONSchema a where
  schema :: proxy a -> Schema
```

Now that `Proxy` has become a suggestively named type variable only we can do something like the following

```
foo :: Schema
foo = schema ([] :: [X])
```

and never have to import `Proxy` at all. I personally think this is a complete hack job though which probably will end up confusing readers.

Comment: The `proxy` "hack job" was perhaps more relevant when `Proxy` wasn't in `base`. Particularly since the `tagged` package actually went through a bunch of versions. But if you're targeting `base>=4.7` it makes more sense to use the concrete type so that readers can follow the Haddock link to make sense of it. (I remember finding this confusing for a while myself.)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but I don't think it explains the core point yet. Now that `Tagged` was mentioned, I notice that my question should rather be *"why use Proxies when you can use Tagged"* (I will update my question in that regard right now). Especially because the answer to *"Do I want to consider typed operations?"* is: No, actually the `a` wouldn't be used in the left hand side of `Schema` (all of its constructors are unparameterised).

Comment: @ChristianConkle I looked at the `proxy a` bit and at the moment I understood what that was good for, I agreed that that's a "hack job" ;) (Just using *any* `* -> *` kind to "wrap" the inner type somehow, because we don't actually care what the wrapper is. So actually that type variable bit in itself is ok, because well we don't care, but instantiating the wrapper to List, or any other concrete type, really makes it awkward.)

Comment: I guess the (theoretical) difference between `proxy a` and `Proxy a` is that a function consuming the latter type could conceivably pattern-match on `Proxy`; the `proxy a` type ensures that the function really won't use the value of its argument at all. But in the presence of `seq` that doesn't matter, I don't think... Does it make a difference to the compiler w/r/t erasing the proxy?

Comment: Does `proxy` vs `Proxy` make a difference for erasing the proxy? Edward Kmett says: *"No, ghc isn't very smart about free theoremish thinking."*

Comment: @nh2 It can't be the case that all of Schema's constructors are untyped because `schema` itself would be. For instance, if you have any desire to make a homogenous structure containing `Schema`s then that phantom variable will get in your way very quickly. On the other hand, if you have `Schema`-combining algebras which act on the typed representation then you can get a lot of safety using the phantom.

Comment: I prefer `proxy` to `Proxy` because I often have access to something that can be unified with `proxy a`, such as a `Nothing` or `[]`, that can be used as an argument directly rather than creating a new `Proxy :: Proxy T`, which I consider excessively verbose.