# What would the type of a list of cascading functions be?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, dependent-type

In Haskell syntax, we can have a (abstract) type like `[a -> b]`, which is a list of functions a to b.  A concrete type of this would be `[Int -> Int]`, such as `map (*) [1..10]`. Is it possible to have a list of cascading functions in a type like `[a -> b, b -> c, c -> d, ...]`? The individual elements of the list are all different (I think) so I don't think it's possible. But is it possible with dependent types? What would its type signature be (preferably in pseudo-Haskell syntax)?

Comment: You can't do that with plain lists in Haskell, but it is possible.  Look at the HList library for heterogeneous lists.  Be warned that there are a lot of extensions used by that library to get such dynamic behavior.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565306/how-to-define-a-multiple-composition-function....

Comment: This is a duplicate of (a subset of) the question jamshidh linked. This question states the issue much more directly, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with a plain list, but you could construct your own list-like type as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data CascadingList i o where
    Id :: CascadingList i i
    Cascade :: (b -> o) -> CascadingList i b -> CascadingList i o
```

Then you could make these `CascadingList`s as follows:

```
addOnePositive :: CascadingList Int Bool
addOnePositive = Cascade (>0) $ Cascade (+1) $ Id
```

You could 'collapse' the lists:

```
collapse :: CascadingList a b -> a -> b
collapse Id = id
collapse (Cascade f c) = f . collapse c
```

Then you would have

```
collapse addOnePositive 0 == True
```

Note that this does not take into account the types of the intermediate functions, so it may not be what you are looking for.

---

I've just realised that this is closer to something like [c -> d, b -> c, a -> b]. It's an easy change to make it closer to your intentions; I could edit it but I think you get the idea.

Comment: As I had noted in my [answer to the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26566362/1186208), the follow-up question (and observation) is: what does such a collection give you over function composition? (The same construction with a different `Category` may be a different matter...)

Comment: One potential advantage I can see is that you can extract the composed functions from this kind of structure, but that is not so with simple function composition. A contrived example: ``(+1) . (-1) == (-1) . (+1)``, but ``[(+1),(-1)] /= [(-1),(+1)]`` (abusing notation obviously).

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed that too. But you can't do much with them; among other things, you can't predict their types from outside of the GADT.

Answer (score 5):

Using `DataKinds`, you can expose the interior types of the collection, which may make using the constituent parts easier:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Cascade where
import Control.Monad ((>=>), liftM)
import Control.Category ((>>>))

data Cascade (cs :: [*]) where
  End :: Cascade '[a]
  (:>>>) :: (a -> b) -> Cascade (b ': cs) -> Cascade (a ': b ': cs)
infixr 5 :>>>

-- a small example
fs :: Cascade '[ String, Int, Float ]
fs = read :>>> fromIntegral :>>> End

-- alternate using functions from one chain then the other
zigzag :: Cascade as -> Cascade as -> Cascade as
zigzag End End = End
zigzag (f :>>> fs) (_ :>>> gs) = f :>>> zigzag gs fs

-- compose a chain into a single function
compose :: Cascade (a ': as) -> a -> Last (a ': as)
compose End = id
compose (f :>>> fs) = f >>> compose fs

-- generalizing Either to a union of multiple types
data OneOf (cs :: [*]) where
  Here :: a -> OneOf (a ': as)
  There :: OneOf as -> OneOf (a ': as)

-- start the cascade at any of its entry points
fromOneOf :: Cascade cs -> OneOf cs -> Last cs
fromOneOf fs (Here a) = compose fs a
fromOneOf (_ :>>> fs) (There o) = fromOneOf fs o

-- generalizing (,) to a product of multiple types
data AllOf (cs :: [*]) where
  None :: AllOf '[]
  (:&) :: a -> AllOf as -> AllOf (a ': as)
infixr 5 :&

-- end the cascade at all of its exit points
toAllOf :: Cascade (a ': as) -> a -> AllOf (a ': as)
toAllOf End a        = a :& None
toAllOf (f :>>> fs)  a = a :& toAllOf fs (f a)

-- start anywhere, and end everywhere after that
fromOneOfToAllOf :: Cascade cs -> OneOf cs -> OneOf (Map AllOf (Tails cs))
fromOneOfToAllOf fs (Here a) = Here $ toAllOf fs a
fromOneOfToAllOf (_ :>>> fs) (There o) = There $ fromOneOfToAllOf fs o

-- type level list functions
type family Map (f :: a -> b) (as :: [a]) where
  Map f '[] = '[]
  Map f (a ': as) = f a ': Map f as

type family Last (as :: [*]) where
  Last '[a] = a
  Last (a ': as) = Last as

type family Tails (as :: [a]) where
  Tails '[] = '[ '[] ]
  Tails (a ': as) = (a ': as) ': Tails as

-- and you can do Monads too!
data CascadeM (m :: * -> *) (cs :: [*]) where
  EndM :: CascadeM m '[a]
  (:>=>) :: (a -> m b) -> CascadeM m (b ': cs) -> CascadeM m (a ': b ': cs)
infixr 5 :>=>

composeM :: Monad m => CascadeM m (a ': as) -> a -> m (Last (a ': as))
composeM EndM = return
composeM (f :>=> fs) = f >=> composeM fs

fromOneOfM :: Monad m => CascadeM m cs -> OneOf cs -> m (Last cs)
fromOneOfM fs (Here a) = composeM fs a
fromOneOfM (_ :>=> fs) (There o) = fromOneOfM fs o

-- end the cascade at all of its exit points
toAllOfM :: Monad m => CascadeM m (a ': as) -> a -> m (AllOf (a ': as))
toAllOfM EndM a        = return $ a :& None
toAllOfM (f :>=> fs)  a = do
  as <- toAllOfM fs =<< f a
  return $ a :& as

-- start anywhere, and end everywhere after that
fromOneOfToAllOfM :: Monad m => CascadeM m cs -> OneOf cs -> m (OneOf (Map AllOf (Tails cs)))
fromOneOfToAllOfM fs (Here a) = Here `liftM` toAllOfM fs a
fromOneOfToAllOfM (_ :>=> fs) (There o) = There `liftM` fromOneOfToAllOfM fs o
```

Comment: I think `Chain` could also be implemented as a (closed) type family, because the type parameter `cs` dictates exactly what constructors will be used.

Comment: Christian Conkle: Yeah, I did that [here for `OneOf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414521/types-for-parser-combinators). I'm monkeying with it now.

Comment: Christian Conkle: I gave up on closed type families for now, as I kept getting injective type errors when I tried to do anything interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A small improvement on scrambledeggs' answer, addressing some of the comments:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable

data CascadingList i o where
    Id :: CascadingList i i
    Cascade :: Typeable b =>  (b -> o) -> CascadingList i b -> CascadingList i o
```

Now when you pattern match on `Cascade`, you can at least try and guess which type `b` is by using [the `eqT` and `cast` functions from `Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Typeable.html#g:4), and if you guess right you can actually use the inside functions.  Mild downside is it only works for types that have a `Typeable` instance (which GHC at least can derive).